# How can I get value from user custom field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redmine, custom-fields

I have a calculated field in which I want to add a value from a previously created custom field by user (position, manager)

example here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg9uX.png

I managed to pass to the field by username using

```
User.current.id
```

How can I pass these 2 fields into a computed
tried to pass the value cfs[22]
unfortunately it didn't work out

Comment: are you trying to do it in Redmine only or need to do it using API or any integration?

Answer (score 0):

To **access** a custom field value which id = 10, try this:

```
# Getting the current User object
u = User.current
# Accessing the value for custom field which id = 10
u.custom_field_value(10)
```

To **assign** a value to a custom field which id = 10 , this code should work:

```
# Getting the current User object
u = User.current
# Assigning the value 'value' to the custom field which id = 10
u.custom_field_values=({'10'=>'value'})
# Persisting the change
u.save
```

You can combine the methods to, for instance, assign a custom field value which id = 11 with the custom field value which id = 10:

```
u.custom_field_values=({'11'=>u.custom_field_value(10)})
# Remember to persist the change
u.save
```

The `rails c` can come in handy for you to explore the Object methods.